# How can I reduce the width of column in Oracle (SQL Plus) with TIMESTAMP datatype?

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, width, sqlplus

In SQL Plus output it is taking up much more space than it needs and I'd like to reduce it from say 50 chars to 20.

Comment: Do you mean in SQLPlus output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you reduce the width to 20 it won't be wide enough for the default `TIMESTAMP` or `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` format. When that happens, SQLPlus will wrap the value.

Assume table `b` has timestamp column `TS`:

```
COLUMN ts FORMAT A20
SELECT ts FROM b;

TS
--------------------
25-APR-13 11.28.40.1
50000 AM
```

To cut down the width even further, decide which information you want and format accordingly. The Oracle DateTime and Timestamp formatting codes are listed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924).

Note that SQLPlus won't let you specify a date format with the `COLUMN` statement. That's why I used `FORMAT A20` above. You can get it to 19 characters if you drop fractional seconds and use a 24-hour clock instead of AM/PM, and drop the time zone:

```
COLUMN TSFormatted FORMAT A20
SELECT TO_CHAR(ts, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TSFormatted FROM b;

TSFORMATTED
--------------------
04/25/2013 11:28:40
```

If you're willing to drop the century you can get two of the fractional seconds and an exact width of 20:

```
COLUMN TSFormatted FORMAT A20
SELECT TO_CHAR(ts, 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS.FF2') AS TSFormatted from b;

TSFORMATTED
--------------------
04/25/13 11:28:40.15
```

Finally, if you want all of your timestamps to be automatically formatted in a certain way, use `ALTER SESSION`:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS.FF2';
COLUMN ts FORMAT A20
SELECT ts from b; -- don't need to_char because of the default format

TS
--------------------
04/25/13 11:28:40.15
```

Comment: Superb answer. I actually realised 20 was too little and found that 30 was fine too. however, you have some excellent methods there which I shall use too. PS if someone could give me a few more reputation points I could vote for answers as I just joined and cannot do anything yet. Cheers.

Comment: This is helpful, but I don't understand why "COLUMN ts FORMAT A20" is needed after the alter session.  Is there a way to get timestamp to display in 20 characters session-wide independent of the format?

Comment: Sorry @sf_jeff, but I answered that so long ago I don't remember exactly why I put in the `COLUMN ts...` bit. I think maybe it was to drive home the point that the `A20` wrapped with the default formatting (first example in my answer) but didn't after setting the new timestamp format. Whatever the reason, you can definitely leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just a short extension to Ed Gibbs' answer above.
For debugging purposes, I put together this simple LOGIN.SQL file:

```
alter session set container = XEPDB1;
alter session set time_zone = 'Europe/Budapest';
alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
alter session set nls_timestamp_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1';
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1';
set pagesize 9999;
set linesize 9999;
set long 9999;
show linesize pagesize long user;
column added format a22;
column modified format a22;
column deleted format a22;
column localtimestamp format a22;
select localtimestamp from dual;
```

The names "added", "modified" and "deleted" are common column names in my schemas that always hold timestamp values. Now, when I start SQL*Plus, I see (with several empty lines in between):

```
SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Jul 10 13:25:52 2020
Version 18.4.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Last Successful login time: Fri Jul 10 2020 13:14:09 +00:00
Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0
Session altered.
Session altered.
Session altered.
Session altered.
Session altered.
linesize 9999
pagesize 9999
long 9999
USER is "CURRENT_USER"
LOCALTIMESTAMP
----------------------
2020-07-10 15:25:53.2
SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

SUBSTR function will work *some* of the time,once you have converted the timestamp (ie. to_CHAR) but specifying a column in sqlplus gives you more control:

eg:

COLUMN SALARY FORMAT $99,990

Source:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm

I say *some* of the time for substr, as I have seen sqlplus cut off the output, but then still pad the output up to the defined size of the column.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Following the query with "COLUMN column_name FORMAT A30 WORD_WRAPPED /" Solved the problem.

Comment: Glad to help - could you up upvote the answer please in that case?

Comment: Hi, I would do but I'm new and it says it don't got no reputation! Want to throw me a bone and I'll get going on that :-)